# Are there varying levels of ASCAP's "plus" awards?

Tags: composition

ASCAP offers an annual monetary award call the ASCAPlus award to its composer members whose music does not generally get included in its sampling for popular music royalties.  These composers include writers of music for educational use (K-12) as well as "concert music" composers whose music is more likely to be heard in a concert hall than on the radio.

I've applied for this award for the last ten years, and usually receive the same $100.  I know that someone must actually read the award applications to determine the award levels because one year when I neither wrote much nor had much music performed, I did not receive an award.  One year, however, about ten years ago, I earned $250.

Does anyone know whether these awards are a set amount ($100), and they simply award that amount to all the composers who have met a certain threshold for their work?  Or are there other award levels above $100, and I simply do not have the prestige to deserve a higher amount?

I've emailed ASCAP Concert Music -- whose staff is generally very helpful and generous with their time -- but did not get a reply.

EDIT: applying a bounty to hopefully gather some answers...  It's a popular award that many composers take advantage of.  Someone must know how it works!